# react-admin: How to suppress multiple 401 notifications?

Tags: react-admin, admin-on-rest

I'm using react-admin and I have a page that makes api calls via the dataProvider to /posts, but there is also a custom UserMenu that fetches /user, and the authProvider also runs an `AUTH_CHECK` that fetches /session.

On the first page load, all three requests are issued and all three correctly return 401 unauthorized, but then I also get three pop-up notifications with the same message: "**Request failed with status code 401**".

Is there a way to either

1. show this message only once
2. not show any of these messages at all

Also, is there a way to customize the text of this message to something more user friendly?